pyserial lists incorrect serialports on Ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded multiple PCs from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. I'm using multiple python scripts for reading/writing to serial ports.
The strange thing is that when I list the available serial ports using serial.tools.list_ports.comports() on Ubuntu 24.04, it also lists all the dummy /dev/ttyS* (0-31) devices which are non-existent on my hardware.
On the same machines with Ubuntu 22.04, only existing serial ports are listed.
>>> from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
>>> [p.name for p in comports()]

Output on Ubuntu 24.04:
['ttyS0', 'ttyS1', ..., 'ttyS30', 'ttyS31', 'ttyUSB0', ..., 'ttyUSB7']

Output on Ubuntu 22.04:
['ttyUSB0', ..., 'ttyUSB7']

When I run ls /dev on both Ubuntu versions, both list /dev/ttyS0 to  /dev/ttyS31, but pyserial behaves different somehow.
I'm using pyserial verions 3.5.
Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix this?

This is what I found out so far:



Ubuntu Version
Kernel Version




22.04
6.2.0-26-generic


24.04
6.8.0-36-generic



By default, pyserial filters out devices with subsystem platform (There's another discussion if this is correct or not, e.g. this pull request).
However, Ubunt 24.04 (or more precisely newer kernel versions) report a different subsystem serial-base for all the (existing and non-existing) legacy serial ports:



Port Type
Subsystem on Ubuntu 22.04
Subsystem on Ubuntu 24.04




Non-existent ports (/dev/ttyS*)
platform
serial-base


Existing legacy ports (/dev/ttyS*)
pnp
serial-base



Source Code of comports():
https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/list_ports_linux.py
def comports(include_links=False):
    devices = set()
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyS*'))     # built-in serial ports
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyUSB*'))   # usb-serial with own driver
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyXRUSB*')) # xr-usb-serial port exar (DELL Edge 3001)
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyACM*'))   # usb-serial with CDC-ACM profile
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyAMA*'))   # ARM internal port (raspi)
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/rfcomm*'))   # BT serial devices
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyAP*'))    # Advantech multi-port serial controllers
    devices.update(glob.glob('/dev/ttyGS*'))    # https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt

    if include_links:
        devices.update(list_ports_common.list_links(devices))
    return [info
            for info in [SysFS(d) for d in devices]
            if info.subsystem != "platform"]    # hide non-present internal serial ports

Knowing this, I could potentially filter out devices with subsystem serial-base manually in my software, but this would also drop existing legacy serial ports which is not what I want.

i've just recently struck this problem too - the code i've been using for a number of years (based on work by Søren Holm) checked for the serial port's device driver being named "serial8250". if the name matched, then the serial port would be opened and an ioctl/TIOCGSERIAL call performed to retrieve the UART "type"; if the "type" was non-zero then the serial port was deemed to be real. if the device driver name was anything other than "serial8250" then the serial port was deemed to be real without need for any checking.
some time between kernel 6.3 and kernel 6.8 the name for ttyS* ports was change from "serial8250" to just "port". this broke the above checking algorithm, with the name "port" now being too generic to rely upon. i have asked a question about this here:
changes to serial driver name with kernel 6.8 and later
i have been working towards an alternative test. it is written in Pascal (FPC), although you should be able to translate it into python without too much trouble:
program project1;
uses SysUtils, BaseUnix, TermIO;

var DeviceName:string;
            SR:TSearchRec;
            FD:longint;
          tios:TermIOS;
      n, c, PT:integer;

begin
  n:=0;
  c:=0;
  if FindFirst('/dev/tty*', faAnyFile , SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    DeviceName:=SR.Name;

    if (DeviceName<>'.') and (DeviceName<>'..') then                           // exclude '.' and '..'
    if fpAccess('/dev/'+DeviceName, R_OK+W_OK)=0 then                          // exclude devices we have NO ACCESS to
    if FileExists('/sys/class/tty/'+DeviceName+'/device/driver')  or           // this suffices with FPC prior to 3.20
       DirectoryExists('/sys/class/tty/'+DeviceName+'/device/driver')  then    // from FPC 3.20 onwards we need this instead
    begin
      if FileExists('/sys/class/tty/'+DeviceName+'/type') then PT:=1           // port type 1 = fixed serial port
                                                          else PT:=2;          // port type 2 = removable/USB
      if PT=1 then
      begin
        FD:=fpOpen('/dev/'+DeviceName, O_RDWR or O_NONBLOCK or O_NOCTTY);
        if FD<0 then PT:=0 else                                                // -1, could not open handle -> failure
        begin
          if fpIOCtl(FD,TCGETS,@tios)<>0 then PT:=0                            // TCGETS: on success 0 is returned,
                                         else inc(n);                          //         on error -1 is returned
          fpClose(FD)
        end
      end;

      if PT<>0 then inc(c);                                                    // count total number of ports
      case PT of 1:writeln('* ', DeviceName);                                  // fixed serial port, verified as real
                 2:writeln('  ', DeviceName)                                   // removable (USB) serial port
      end  {of case}
    end
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;

  if n<>0 then writeln('(', n, ' fixed devices)');
  if c=0 then writeln('no serial ports found');
  FindClose(SR)
end.

the test for the device driver being called "serial8250" has now been replaced with a check for the existence of a "type" pseudo-file, and the ioctl/TIOCGSERIAL call result replaced with ioctl/TCGETS simply succeeding (the returned data is not used). an fpAccess call has also been added, effectively to ensure no results are returned if the user is not a member of the dialout group.
if you translate this into python, please do post the resultant code. the discussion where this code was developed can be found here:
https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,69437.msg541387.html#msg541387
and the original C++ code by Søren Holm can be found about 1/3 the way down this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301542/7879071
